# IIS 7.5 Request Filtering

Tags: iis7

I keep getting 404.7 (FILE_EXTENSION_DENIED) on a sub directory I have under my Default Web Site.

Request Filtering allows htm and html files on the server level and the site level.

A few months ago I created a folder under Default Web Site to test some proof of concept stuff and have had no problems.

A week or so ago I added a folder with Piwik php \ html code underneath 'Default Web Site' and request filtering has decided to block html extensions.

My question is can anyone tell me any reason why my one folder would not have html files blocked and yet another added a few weeks later does have html files blocked?

**EDIT:**
I *believe* I installed Request Filtering a much longer time ago before both of these websites were created when I was doing some Web Deploy stuff. Other than that I have not knowingly applied any request filters to any of the websites.

Comment: Can you clarify this question as to if you had added Request Filtering yourself, and to where and what if so?

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: Also, I fixed the issue by removing .htm and .html from the list but I am jsut wondering what could cause one to have such different restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

Open up IIS manager. 
Click on your site on the left hand side.  On the right hand side double click Request Filtering.

Now under the File Name and Extension tabs, make sure the extension of the page you are trying to allow is allowed (set to true).  So if you are trying to serve a .py page then .py extension needs to be true.

Browse through the different tabs, and make sure your folder is not in a hidden segment, or if there are any http verbs (update, delete, insert) which you have blocked via request filtering which is causing your headache.